# Parsing an HTML page in Wordpress and PHP, how do I select a specific table?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Parsing an HTML page in Wordpress and PHP, how do I select a specific table?
Right now, I request a specific page, and I am able to return the "body" section with my code.

However, I'd like to only return the "myTable" fragment.:

```
<table id="myTable" class="display" table width="60%" border="1">
```

My code:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( $request_url );
return $response['body'];
```

HTML looks similar to this:

```
<html>
…
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="display" table width="60%" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Number </th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>123456789101112</td>
<td>Foobar makes the best foo I ever barred!</td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parsing with what? Simple HTML DOM? DOMDocument?

Comment: Is there a way to "grab" the response by the tag like the ['body'] syntax? If not, then yes, I could use simpleHTMLDom library. How would that conflict with Wordpress if I added it to my plug-in?

Comment: Just by itself only if you're using JavaScript. But that will work on front end only. If you want to manipulate DOM on the back end, you'll need some kind of DOM parser. I had to use similar method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114429/removing-unwanted-elements-from-table-simple-html-dom)